# How to fix the AttributeError that occurs when no music file is added to the pygame mixer?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is for playing music from a .WAV file using tkinter, but when I press the play button without importing any audio file, the following error occurs

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Python3/lib/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Files/Stack Overflow/no-music-file-error.py", line 23, in <lambda>
    file_play.config(text="Play", command=lambda:[play_file()])
  File "/Files/Stack Overflow/no-music-file-error.py", line 30, in play_file
    pygame.mixer.music.load(window.filename)
  File "/Python3/lib/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2354, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

and the program stops.

I want it to produce a message that tells it doesn't work when no audio file is imported when the button is pressed.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
import os
import pygame

#Variable

#function
def start():
    global x
    x = 1
    pygame.mixer.init()
    file_select.place(x=200, y=10)
    file_play.place(x=280, y=10)
    volume_S.place(x=150, y=35)
    file_select.config(text="Open FIle", command=lambda:[open_file()])
    file_play.config(text="Play", command=lambda:[play_file()])

def open_file():
    window.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file",filetypes = (("all files","*.*"), ("jpeg files","*.jpg")))
    print(window.filename)

def play_file():
    pygame.mixer.music.load(window.filename)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0)

def volumeset(self):
    pvolume=float(volume_S.get())
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(pvolume*0.1)

#File_location
print (os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) )

#Windowm
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("796x448")
window.resizable(0,0)

#Widgets_setup
file_select = tk.Button(window, font=("Calbri", 10))
file_play = tk.Button(window, font=("Calbri", 10))
volume_S = tk.Scale(window, variable=int, command=volumeset, orient="horizontal", showvalue=False, tickinterval=1, to=10, length=200)

#Window_mainloop
start()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: '"it occurs error ..."* - What is the error message?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: if u want an output when there is filenotfounderror try reading the link.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed if you don't [edit] it and add a copy of the error message including a complete backtrace to the statement causing the problem if possible.

Comment: The guy doesn't answer ,anyways thanks will take a look at it.@martineau

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the `AttributeError` you're getting, you need to change the `play_file()` function to handle the situation where the user hasn't opened a file first. The best way to do this of course is with a user-friendly error message — and `tkinter` has several built-in (here's some documentation on its [Standard Dialogs](https://web.archive.org/web/20201121191823id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm)).

```
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror  # Add this near top of file with other imports.
```

Then modify the function like this:

```
def play_file():
    try:
        audio_filename = window.filename
    except AttributeError:
        showerror(title='File playing error', message="Please open a file to play first!")
        return
    pygame.mixer.music.load(audio_filename)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

The new result when the <kbd>Play</kbd> button is pressed without opening an audio file first:

[image: screenshot of error message]

Comment: Yanbunny: Doesn't this answer your question?